# Xcode Cloud workflows are not visible by other developer in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

I am using Xcode Cloud workflows for my app. I see everything related to workflows right in Xcode and also on App Store Connect website.
When I granted to other developer access to this app with *developer* role he started to see workflows on App Store Connect website but not in Xcode.

Why is that? An how can we fix it?

Xcode version is 13.3

Comment: He needs to be logged in with a valid account in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document:

- Ask coworkers to start using Xcode Cloud as described in [Connect your personal SCM account to Xcode Cloud](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-xcode-cloud-for-your-team#Connect-your-personal-SCM-account-to-Xcode-Cloud).

Since the others could see the workflows on App Store Connect, the Apple Account is working.
If still couldn't get from the Xcode, there are still two things to confirm:

1. Make sure they don't see any SCM link errors on App Store Connect's workflow page. If there are, please link as instruction.
2. Make sure they configure the correct Apple Account & SCM Account in Xcode, same as App Store Connect.

Hope this is helpful to you.